# understanding app.mountpath property of express

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to express framework and trying to learn basics but i don't understand app.mountpath property of express js .

i have gone through the docs but still very confused.

Any explaination is appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any express application (like `var app = express()`) has its own [`Router`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router). You can use the [`app.use()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use) function to mount routers into each other e.g.:

```
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use('/route', router);
```

This mounts `router` at the `/route` route pattern of the `app`'s Router. The `mountpath` property simply contains the route pattern where a specific sub-app was mounted i.e. in the above example:

```
console.log(router.mountpath); // /route
```

**Update:** Maybe an additional remark about the point of this property. [The docs show](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.mountpath) that mounting a sub-app abstracts the full path from the sub-app e.g.:

```
router.get('/sub', function(req, res) { ... });
```

This route is actually reached by `/route/sub` and not by `/sub` as we mounted it at `/route`. So if you want to access the path where a mounted sub-app is actually located you can use the `app.mountpath` property.

Comment: what does mount means?

Comment: Mounting means that you basically put an express app at a specific place inside another express app. So in my above example I say: Hey, please let the `router` app handle any request which goes to `/route`. This allows a structure which is easier to understand and to maintain.

Comment: @Jones yeah understood.

Could you please suggest me any article on express where i could clearly understand all the express properties and functions and also error handling middle ware?

Comment: I doubt that there is a single article covering everything. I would recommend to get started with a course ([this one](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/building-blocks-of-express-js) looks promising) and then continue to understand the docs, they are really the best reference.

Comment: Okey Thank you  :)